# Ubuntu 18.04 Wi-fi not working

Tags: wireless

I've done a clean install of ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I've managed to get wired to work(dont rly know how) but am struggling to work out wireless. I've tried many fixes from this website or others. I'm new to ubuntu so pls tell me what info you need, thanks. I get the message "Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed"

Result of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b3] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0775]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Limited BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 01)
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0642]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] [1002:6604] (rev ff)
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

--NEW DEVELOPMENT--
I was able to connect to a wifi hotspot from my phone, by can't connect via wifi to my home router. I don't know if this changes anything, will reset router and see what happens.(Same result, no improvements)

Results for `dmesg | grep ath`

```
[   17.210621] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   18.816504] ath: phy0: WB335 2-ANT card detected
[   18.816506] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   18.823164] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   18.824257] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   18.824259] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   18.824259] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   18.824261] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   18.824261] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   18.830265] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  868.705852] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071028.417:37): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[  868.706719] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071028.417:38): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[  868.706723] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071028.417:39): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 1572.089299] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071731.780:40): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 1572.089755] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071731.780:41): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 1572.090113] audit: type=1107 audit(1550071731.780:42): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 2633.918842] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072793.598:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=12986 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2640.130297] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072799.810:61): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13063 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2647.967962] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072807.646:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13136 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2658.997519] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072818.678:87): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13317 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2664.180435] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072823.862:101): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2670.080224] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072829.758:114): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13492 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2675.659869] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072835.338:127): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13590 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2682.699163] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072842.378:142): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13669 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2688.676249] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072848.354:156): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13742 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2693.912793] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072853.594:165): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=13823 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2704.304787] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072863.986:177): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=14001 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2712.617530] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072872.298:191): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=14075 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2718.653004] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072878.334:201): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=14152 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2733.033214] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072892.713:227): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=14388 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2736.822451] audit: type=1400 audit(1550072896.501:239): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=14465 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 2912.345066] audit: type=1107 audit(1550073072.020:314): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 2912.349890] audit: type=1107 audit(1550073072.024:315): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 2912.350060] audit: type=1107 audit(1550073072.024:316): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=2772 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 7298.359733] audit: type=1107 audit(1550077457.970:322): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=19188 label="snap.libreoffice.calc" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 7845.705239] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078005.311:343): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.180" pid=19188 label="snap.libreoffice.calc" peer_pid=19635 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 7870.571846] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078030.179:350): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=19714 label="snap.libreoffice.calc" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 7892.100786] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078051.706:375): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.184" pid=19714 label="snap.libreoffice.calc" peer_pid=19792 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 7937.051932] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078096.654:382): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=19875 label="snap.libreoffice.calc" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8177.383609] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078336.980:397): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8177.383813] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078336.980:398): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8177.383989] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078336.980:399): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8276.005882] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078435.601:400): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8276.006888] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078435.601:401): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 8276.006892] audit: type=1107 audit(1550078435.601:402): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9414.011063] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079573.580:403): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9414.011930] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079573.580:404): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9414.012266] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079573.580:405): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9426.290417] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079585.856:406): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9426.291551] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079585.860:407): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9426.292547] audit: type=1107 audit(1550079585.860:408): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9869.048709] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080028.608:409): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9869.049051] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080028.608:410): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9869.049379] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080028.608:411): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9884.609075] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080044.168:412): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9884.609361] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080044.168:413): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 9884.609565] audit: type=1107 audit(1550080044.168:414): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=20829 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13518.018793] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083677.522:415): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13518.019325] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083677.522:416): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13518.019574] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083677.522:417): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13604.001873] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083763.501:418): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13604.002993] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083763.505:419): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[13604.002998] audit: type=1107 audit(1550083763.505:420): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[14027.533657] audit: type=1107 audit(1550084187.030:421): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[14027.534810] audit: type=1107 audit(1550084187.030:422): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="GetDisplayDevice" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[14027.534814] audit: type=1107 audit(1550084187.030:423): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/UPower" interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.UPower" pid=30674 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=935 peer_label="unconfined"
[15324.560052] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x826c
[15324.560053] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[15324.560054] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[15324.560055] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[15324.560056] ath: Country alpha2 being used: PT
[15324.560057] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[15324.560058] ath: regdomain 0x826c dynamically updated by country IE
[15859.763935] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x826c
[15859.763936] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[15859.763937] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[15859.763939] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[15859.763940] ath: Country alpha2 being used: PT
[15859.763941] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[15859.763942] ath: regdomain 0x826c dynamically updated by country IE
[16856.266690] audit: type=1400 audit(1550087015.719:450): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=2602 comm="apparmor_parser"
[16943.878506] audit: type=1400 audit(1550087103.330:502): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=3445 comm="apparmor_parser"
[16951.365746] audit: type=1400 audit(1550087110.817:511): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.libreoffice.math" pid=3514 comm="apparmor_parser"
[17327.283131] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x826c
[17327.283132] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[17327.283134] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[17327.283136] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[17327.283138] ath: Country alpha2 being used: PT
[17327.283139] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[17327.283141] ath: regdomain 0x826c dynamically updated by country IE
[20550.258442] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090709.643:518): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=5170 label="snap.libreoffice.base" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[20553.361167] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090712.747:523): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.328" pid=5170 label="snap.libreoffice.base" peer_pid=5602 peer_label="unconfined"
[20553.361682] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090712.747:524): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.328" pid=5170 label="snap.libreoffice.base" peer_pid=5602 peer_label="unconfined"
[20563.638617] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090723.023:525): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=5652 label="snap.libreoffice.impress" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[20576.200244] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090735.587:526): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=5346 label="snap.libreoffice.impress" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
[20579.958885] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090739.347:533): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.328" pid=5346 label="snap.libreoffice.impress" peer_pid=5602 peer_label="unconfined"
[20620.688948] audit: type=1107 audit(1550090780.079:541): pid=772 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=5920 label="snap.libreoffice.impress" peer_pid=742 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: All looks great, Wi-Fi should work. I have no ideas.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `dmesg | grep -ath`

Comment: The correct command is `dmesg | grep ath`.